# Quartz How do I put triggers in a state where they wont re-fire a misfire

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler

I have an interesting issue with our web application.  We recently had a huge concurrency problem with Quartz firing off the same java class in hundreds of threads at once causing contention on the database and completely locking our application.  Before we were able to address the underlying issue, I had to set all misfire_instr to "1" (Do not re-fire a misfire) on the database table qrtz_triggers to get the application to come up and serve normal traffic.  We then manually fired off the missed schedules slowly to avoid the concurrency issue.

I have fixed the concurrency issue and am ready to hot-deploy our application, but am afraid if I set the misfire_instr back to 2 (re-fire misfires), the missed schedules will re-fire again based on prev_fire_time?

Proposed solution - set prev_fire_time to a couple minutes before the next_fire_time so it thinks the last schedules went off.  Is my assumption here correct that a schedule is considered missed if the prev_fire_time is before the last time represented by the cron expression?

I also see that schedules which have yet to run have -1 in the column, is this the default for a new schedule, perhaps I should be using this value instead?

Comment: Can you please post a printout of the relevant `QRTZ` tables?

Comment: I'm not sure that would help.  I have solved the problem anyway.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since we needed this to go in immediately, I decided to just try my luck with using -1 as the prev_fire_time value (and updating the triggers back to 2).  This worked as expected.

Answer (score 0):

This came up for me recently. The meaning of the value in the MISFIRE_INSTR column varies in part by the kind of trigger. Refer to the [Quartz client source code](https://github.com/quartznet/quartznet/blob/main/src/Quartz/MisfireInstruction.cs) for a friendly mapping of the numeric column value to a meaning but here is a summary:

For all triggers:

```
  SmartPolicy = 0 (usually 'fire now')
  IgnoreMisfirePolicy = -1
```

For a SimpleTrigger:

```
  FireNow = 1
  RescheduleNowWithExistingRepeatCount = 2
  RescheduleNowWithRemainingRepeatCount = 3
  RescheduleNextWithRemainingCount = 4
  RescheduleNextWithExistingCount = 5
```

For a CronTrigger/CalendarIntervalTrigger/DailyTimeIntervalTrigger:

```
  FireOnceNow = 1
  DoNothing = 2
```